# Term Store Management availability in Site Collection Site Settings in SharePoint 2010 Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

In normal SharePoint 2010 Server, I see it fine, but can't get to it from a site collection on SharePoint 2010 Online.  Is this even an option with the online version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  It is a hidden feature where there is no UI to activate it.  You must upload a solution package to activate the hidden feature.  Here is one:

http://www.metaengine.com/sptermcloud

Just upload to the solution store, activate solution and the Term Store Management link will now be available.